# Load an existing database to Universal app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to load an existing database file in a Universal 8.1 app.

I installed all required packages, and I'm using `SQLitePCL` wrapper.

when I try to open the db file using this command:

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("test.db");
```

It's creating a new empty database. (I mean, every `SELECT` command fails with no such table error. So it's not my database, it's a new one.)

Also,

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("ms-appx:///test.db");
```

throws this exception:

> Unable to open the database file: ms-appx:///test.db Details: unable to open database file

my test.db is located into root of Shared project, with `Build Action` set to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` set to `If Newer`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me?

- Please accept my apologize if this is a stupid question, I'm new to WinRT programming.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution about `sqlite-net` wrapper, which also works for `SQLitePCL` here: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/import-an-already-existing-sqlite-database-in-a-windows-8-application/

The summary is, those wrapper look for the database inside `LocalStorage` folder. So you'll need to copy the file to `LocalStorage` before accessing the database.

```
private async Task CopyDatabase()
{
    bool isDatabaseExisting = false;
 
    try
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("people.db");
        isDatabaseExisting = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        isDatabaseExisting = false;
    }
 
    if (!isDatabaseExisting)
    {
        StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("people.db");
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

After that, database will be accessible using this line of code:

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection("test.db");
```

**However, the problem is that I'll have two instances of database file stored in phone. I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone help?**

Comment: The property `Build Action` of `people.db` must be `Content`. If it is not set the database is not included in the application.

Comment: Where should I put my "people.db" in the project? ... Should I put it in Asset folder, or I should create a custom folder for it Or it should be put in the root folder? anyone can help please.